# Adding space between image and text in QPushButton

Tags: html, css, qt, qtextdocument

I have a rich text button, which is a descendant of `QPushButton` and uses `QTextDocument` for limited HTML support. I need to create a button, which has an icon on the left and a caption on the right (with some space between image and text).

So, let's assume that we have `set_html(const QString& html)` method. I failed to add the space between image and text via `style` attribute (with `margin`) in `img` tag. What will be the input string for that method?

Comment: Did you use [`QPushButton::setIcon()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#icon-prop) or did you put the icon as `<img ...>` into the HTML text? In the latter case, why don't you include some `&#160;` ("non-backspace" characters) between image and text?

Comment: I use <img> tag. I'd like to use offset in pixels.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Though the "non-backspace" character idea could provide proper scale-up for free (e.g. if font sizes may vary). I'm not sure if this could be an issue on high-resolution displays as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following verbose workaround (due to limited HTML support in QLabel):

```html
<table><tr><td><img src=":/save_monitor_settings.png"/></td><td style="padding-left:10px;">Some text</td></tr></table>
```